# datetime variable comparison returns blank

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm trying to get data from my mariaDB table using a SQL Statement with where and datetime field. When I enter the string like Datum >= "2018-01-18 15:16:17" the result is as expected. When I compare the variable Datum >= $ymdt I receive a blank page. I tried different delimiters ('") for the string. I tried with other fields like City successful. Where is my problem with this datetime?

```
<?php

$dat="2018-01-25 15:16:17"; 
$ymdt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dat)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo "<p> Debug Section<br>";
echo $dat;
Output: 2018-01-25 15:16:17
echo "<br>";
echo $ymdt;
Output: 2018-01-25 15:16:17
echo "</p>";
```

this following line returns a blank table, why?

```
foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM wetterdaten where datum >= $ymdt ORDER BY id DESC") as $zeile) {}
```

this following line returns the table filled from date (datetime field mysql) as expected

```
foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM wetterdaten where datum >= '2018-01-25 15:16:17' ORDER BY id DESC") as $zeile) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM wetterdaten where datum >= $ymdt ORDER BY id DESC") as $zeile) {}
```

> this line returns a blank table, why?

Because in this example, your date/time string is not quoted. This query will be filled like:

```
where datum >= 2018-01-25 15:16:17
```

You need to wrap your `$ymdt` variable in single quotes:

```
foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM wetterdaten where datum >= '$ymdt' ORDER BY id DESC") as $zeile) {}
```

A better solution would be to use a prepared statement, that way you don't have to worry about quoting and escaping strings yourself.

Comment: wow, quick Response. Thanks, that's working. Beginners problems ....